# Json schema registry spring cloud kafka

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsonschema, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-schema-registry

i work with spring cloud stream kafka , i have an issue with with json schema registry , i save my schema with the api of confluent but always i had this problem

> org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred
> in message handler
> [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$ProducerConfigurationMessageHandler@65ffd83e];
> nested exception is
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error
> retrieving JSON schema:
> {"$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#"

Ps: the schema used is too long

What might the problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem: I just add
`use.latest.version: true`
to get the schema from the server of schema registry.

Without this option Spring will not get the actual version of the schema.